# C# Service with Interop.Excel not working as a service but only locally

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I need help with a service in C# I am fixing. This service does (in order):

1. copies a XLSM file from a NAS folder in local WM;
2. parse this file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (vers. 15.0.4795.1000 from NuGET);
3. fill a table in a DB with data extracted from this Excel file.

This service is written with C# in VS2019 in the same VM where it should run. If I run it in debug mode with VS everything works, so I installed it in the VM but now it does not work anymore, I keep getting this error as soon as step 2 starts:

System.Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Cannot access file XXXX.xslm

The file XXXX.xlsm is the file copied from NAS in the local VM and is opened in read only mode; so step 1 is correctly executed. The service runs with the same user I use to log in the VM.

It it may help, in this VM Excel 2019 is installed, and anyway it works when I run in debug mode.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using absolute path to access to to file?

Usually service execution folder is different than the execution folder of an normal application and depends on the execution context of the service.

If you have to use relative path try with:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

To find the right path.

If path is ok check that the service account user has valid rights to access and (if you need that) edit the file.

Comment: Thank you for your help Fabio. The folder is in C:\XXX therefore I am using an absolute path so I don't think this is an issue. As for the user privileges, the service is running with the same user I log in to the VM so I don't think this could be an issue either

Comment: Did you see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65234761/only-in-windows-service-system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x800a03ec?rq=1)? By the way I suggest you to not use interop in a windows service. If you can it would better to use OLEDB or any library that can read an excel file without the user interaction. When I have to import excel files (or edit them) I use EEPLUS in my projects usually.